# How do I set the compilation mode of scala-native to 'release'?

Tags: scala-native

The scala-native site says there is a faster executable option, but it doesn't state how to set it in SBT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `nativeMode := "release"` to your build.sbt

Other options are listed here: https://www.scala-native.org/en/v0.3.9-docs/user/sbt.html#sbt-settings-and-tasks